# Mean of the Chi Distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, self-learning, expected-value, chi-squared

I'm trying to find an online derivation of why the mean of the Chi-Distribution with $n$ degrees of freedom is $$E(\chi_n)= \sqrt2 \frac{ \Gamma(\frac{n+1}{2})}{\Gamma(\frac{n}{2})}$$

Is it too involved to find online? Does anyone have any idea how I could derive it using something much more well-known (and available) online like the chi-squared distribution?

I've looked everywhere online, and even looked through some of the books referenced on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi_distribution) and [WolframAlpha's](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChiDistribution.html) pages on the Chi Distribution. None of them list how to derive it, they just have the final answer.

Comment: Find it as $E(\chi_n)=E(\sqrt{\chi_n^2})=\int \sqrt{x}f_{\chi^2_n}(x)\,dx=\cdots$, i.e. using the pdf $f_{\chi^2_n}$ of [chi-squared distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_distribution).

Comment: Hmm that might actually work! But how do you reach that form? Where did you get that $\sqrt{x}$ from?

Comment: It is just an application of [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician) theorem. You have two options: find  $E(\chi_n)$ from the pdf of $\chi_n$, or find it using the pdf of $\chi^2_n$ as indicated in my last comment.